# django python manage.py runserver RuntimeError: Settings already configured

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-dev-server

I am quite new to Django and Python. My environ is Win7 and Python3.4. Now following the tutorial in Django Official Website to build a web app. At first, everything works quite well and output are all expected and correct. But today when I re-run the command "python manage.py runserver", it gives me very strange err message as follows. Help please, many thanks!

```
$ python manage.py runserver 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\360\My Cloud\5 Software\26 Eclipse\1 Python\1TDD_Django\tdd_django\mysite\polls\admin.py", line 34, in <module>
    settings.configure()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 58, in configure
    raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.')
RuntimeError: Settings already configured.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#either-configure-or-django-settings-module-is-required):

> If you set **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**, access settings values somehow, then call **configure()**, Django will raise a *RuntimeError* indicating that settings have already been configured.
>
> Also, it’s an error to call configure() more than once, or to call configure() after any setting has been accessed.

The problem is, by the time you call `settings.configure()` in *mysite.polls.admin*, settings were already configured. One option for suppressing the error would be adding some sanity check:

```
if not settings.configured:
    settings.configure()
```

Comment: I did notice the docs part but didn't know where to modify it. Thanks! :)